# TFS - Work Items - Is it possible to set a state from any other state without creating all the transitions?

Tags: customization, state, transition, workitem

We have a custom workflow with about 8 Work Item states... and we wanted a 9th one called "cancelled". But it could, in theory, be cancelled at any point of development.

Is there a way to create this state which can come from any other state without having to create 8 transitions ?

Thanks in Advance

~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to add all 8 transitions.